# Find Month difference in php?

Tags: php, datetime, date

Is there any way to find the month difference in PHP? I have the input of from-date 2003-10-17 and to-date 2004-03-24. I need to find how many months there are within these two days. Say if 6 months, I need the output in months only.  Thanks for guiding me for day difference.

I find the solution through MySQL but I need it in PHP. Anyone help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is a month in this case? THe calendar month? 30 days?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=date+difference+php

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Here's a quick one:

```
$date1 = mktime(0,0,0,10,0,2003); // m d y, use 0 for day
$date2 = mktime(0,0,0,3,0,2004); // m d y, use 0 for day

echo round(($date2-$date1) / 60 / 60 / 24 / 30);
```

Comment: This will become more and more inaccurate the farther apart the two dates are and may eventually round the wrong way...

Comment: What will happened if month has `31 days` in case `January, March, May, July, August, October, December` or `28 days` in case `February`, coz you divided by 30.

Answer (score 79):

The easiest way without reinventing the wheel. This'll give you the **full** months difference. I.e. the below two dates are *almost* 76 months apart, but the result is 75 months.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');  // you are required to set a timezone

$date1 = new DateTime('2009-08-12');
$date2 = new DateTime('2003-04-14');

$diff = $date1->diff($date2);

echo (($diff->format('%y') * 12) + $diff->format('%m')) . " full months difference";
```

Comment: great work:just a small question into this how to get number of days using this?

Comment: @noobie Please [RTFM for `DateInterval::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) to find all possible formatting options.

Comment: Weird results: From: 2013-03-01, Until: 2013-04-01, diff year: 0, diff month: 1, diff days: 3. Months with less then 31 days also give diff in months=0

Comment: @thehpi Interesting. But this is bound to be imprecise whatever you do, since "a month" is an terribly vague unit of time. Should it count as one month as soon as a month boundary is crossed between two dates? Or only if a full month lies between them? What is "a full month"? 28 days? 30? 31?

Comment: Use with caution! Difference in months between 01.01.2013 and 31.03.2013 will be 2 months (not 3 as maybe expected!)

Comment: @ValentinDespa Actually the difference between 01.01.2013 and 31.03.2013 is [2 months and 30 days](http://ideone.com/B9qv5O), which is accurate. You would be kind of an optimistic person if you would expect a difference of exactly 3 months :-)

Comment: To get rid of 'Wrong string concatenation operator' in PhpStorm cast string to int:
(((int) $diff->format('%y') * 12) + (int) $diff->format('%m'));

Comment: 2018-04-01 and 2018-07-01 Should be 3 months difference but got 2 months.

Comment: Well, it comes down to how you define "one month". It's a wishy-washy definition. Apparently PHP's definition and yours differ. I'd inspect the remaining day difference and round up if necessary/close enough.

Comment: Would be nice to point out that you can add %R to the format to get negative values depending of which date is greater 
`$diff->format('%R%y') * 12) + $diff->format('%R%m')`

Answer (score 29):

After testing tons of solutions, putting all in a unit test, this is what I come out with:

```
/**
 * Calculate the difference in months between two dates (v1 / 18.11.2013)
 *
 * @param \DateTime $date1
 * @param \DateTime $date2
 * @return int
 */
public static function diffInMonths(\DateTime $date1, \DateTime $date2)
{
    $diff =  $date1->diff($date2);

    $months = $diff->y * 12 + $diff->m + $diff->d / 30;

    return (int) round($months);
}
```

For example it will return (test cases from the unit test):

- 01.11.2013 - 30.11.2013 - 1 month
- 01.01.2013 - 31.12.2013 - 12 months
- 31.01.2011 - 28.02.2011 - 1 month
- 01.09.2009 - 01.05.2010 - 8 months
- 01.01.2013 - 31.03.2013 - 3 months
- 15.02.2013 - 15.04.2013 - 2 months
- 01.02.1985 - 31.12.2013 - 347 months

Notice: Because of the rounding it does with the days, even a half of a month will be rounded, which may lead to issue if you use it with some cases. So DO NOT USE it for such cases, it will cause you issues.

For example:

- 02.11.2013 - 31.12.2013 will return 2, not 1 (as expected).

Comment: nice solution, for example 01.06 - 01.07 gives 0 month (in m), but using days and rounding it works correctly

Comment: Very good solution.

Answer (score 8):

I just wanted to add this if anyone is looking for a simple solution that counts each touched-upon month in stead of complete months, rounded months or something like that.

```
// Build example data
$timeStart = strtotime("2003-10-17");
$timeEnd = strtotime("2004-03-24");
// Adding current month + all months in each passed year
$numMonths = 1 + (date("Y",$timeEnd)-date("Y",$timeStart))*12;
// Add/subtract month difference
$numMonths += date("m",$timeEnd)-date("m",$timeStart);

echo $numMonths;
```

Answer (score 6):

Wow, way to overthink the problem... How about this version:

```
function monthsBetween($startDate, $endDate) {
    $retval = "";

    // Assume YYYY-mm-dd - as is common MYSQL format
    $splitStart = explode('-', $startDate);
    $splitEnd = explode('-', $endDate);

    if (is_array($splitStart) && is_array($splitEnd)) {
        $difYears = $splitEnd[0] - $splitStart[0];
        $difMonths = $splitEnd[1] - $splitStart[1];
        $difDays = $splitEnd[2] - $splitStart[2];

        $retval = ($difDays > 0) ? $difMonths : $difMonths - 1;
        $retval += $difYears * 12;
    }
    return $retval;
}
```

NB: unlike several of the other solutions, this doesn't depend on the date functions added in PHP 5.3, since many shared hosts aren't there yet.

Comment: I just edited this line ```$retval = ($difDays > 0) ? $difMonths : $difMonths - 1;``` to ```$retval = ($difDays >= 0) ? $difMonths : $difMonths - 1;``` So the difference between 2017-02-01 and 2017-03-01 is just 1

Comment: not correct. bettwen 2022-06-15 2023-06-15 = 12 Months. Your code retunt value 11

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

This returns a DateInterval object which has a format method.

Answer (score 2):

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');

$datetime2 = date_create('2013-1-13');

$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

echo $interval->format('%a day %m month %y year');
```

Comment: Day Month Year Difference  in php

Comment: Hi, please add some explanation to why this is a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// get year and month difference

$a1 = '20170401';

$a2 = '20160101'

$yearDiff = (substr($a1, 0, 4) - substr($a2, 0, 4));

$monthDiff = (substr($a1, 4, 2) - substr($a2, 4, 2));

$fullMonthDiff = ($yearDiff * 12) + $monthDiff;

// fullMonthDiff = 16
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my enhanced version of @deceze answer:

```
 /**
 * @param string $startDate
 * Current date is considered if empty string is passed
 * @param string $endDate
 * Current date is considered if empty string is passed
 * @param bool $unsigned
 * If $unsigned is true, difference is always positive, otherwise the difference might be negative
 * @return int
 */
public static function diffInFullMonths($startDate, $endDate, $unsigned = false)
{
    $diff = (new DateTime($startDate))->diff(new DateTime($endDate));
    $reverse = $unsigned === true ? '' : '%r';
    return ((int) $diff->format("{$reverse}%y") * 12) + ((int) $diff->format("{$reverse}%m"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way.

```
function getIntervals(DateTime $from, DateTime $to)
{
    $intervals = [];
    $startDate = $from->modify('first day of this month');
    $endDate = $to->modify('last day of this month');
    while($startDate < $endDate){
        $firstDay = $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $startDate->modify('last day of this month')->modify('+1 day');
        $intervals[] = [
            'firstDay' => $firstDay,
            'lastDay' => $startDate->modify('-1 second')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ];
        $startDate->modify('+1 second');
    }
    return $intervals;
}
$dateTimeFirst = new \DateTime('2013-01-01');
$dateTimeSecond = new \DateTime('2013-03-31');
$interval = getIntervals($dateTimeFirst, $dateTimeSecond);
print_r($interval);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [firstDay] => 2013-01-01 00:00:00
            [lastDay] => 2013-01-31 23:59:59
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [firstDay] => 2013-02-01 00:00:00
            [lastDay] => 2013-02-28 23:59:59
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [firstDay] => 2013-03-01 00:00:00
            [lastDay] => 2013-03-31 23:59:59
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to count full months and day leftovers as month as well to build a line chart labels.

```
/**
 * Calculate the difference in months between two dates
 *
 * @param \DateTime $from
 * @param \DateTime $to
 * @return int
 */
public static function diffInMonths(\DateTime $from, \DateTime $to)
{
    // Count months from year and month diff
    $diff = $to->diff($from)->format('%y') * 12 + $to->diff($from)->format('%m');

    // If there is some day leftover, count it as the full month
    if ($to->diff($from)->format('%d') > 0) $diff++;

    // The month count isn't still right in some cases. This covers it.
    if ($from->format('d') >= $to->format('d')) $diff++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
  # end date is 2008 Oct. 11 00:00:00
  $_endDate = mktime(0,0,0,11,10,2008);
  # begin date is 2007 May 31 13:26:26
  $_beginDate = mktime(13,26,26,05,31,2007);

  $timestamp_diff= $_endDate-$_beginDate +1 ;
  # how many days between those two date
  $days_diff = $timestamp_diff/2635200;

?>
```

Reference: http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php#86916

Comment: Same problem as @Kai's solution, very optimistic assumption that a month has 30 days...

Answer (score -1):

```
function monthsDif($start, $end)
{
    // Assume YYYY-mm-dd - as is common MYSQL format
    $splitStart = explode('-', $start);
    $splitEnd = explode('-', $end);

    if (is_array($splitStart) && is_array($splitEnd)) {
        $startYear = $splitStart[0];
        $startMonth = $splitStart[1];
        $endYear = $splitEnd[0];
        $endMonth = $splitEnd[1];

        $difYears = $endYear - $startYear;
        $difMonth = $endMonth - $startMonth;

        if (0 == $difYears && 0 == $difMonth) { // month and year are same
            return 0;
        }
        else if (0 == $difYears && $difMonth > 0) { // same year, dif months
            return $difMonth;
        }
        else if (1 == $difYears) {
            $startToEnd = 13 - $startMonth; // months remaining in start year(13 to include final month
            return ($startToEnd + $endMonth); // above + end month date
        }
        else if ($difYears > 1) {
            $startToEnd = 13 - $startMonth; // months remaining in start year 
            $yearsRemaing = $difYears - 2;  // minus the years of the start and the end year
            $remainingMonths = 12 * $yearsRemaing; // tally up remaining months
            $totalMonths = $startToEnd + $remainingMonths + $endMonth; // Monthsleft + full years in between + months of last year
            return $totalMonths;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ammended - changed $startToEnd = 12 - $startMonth; to $startToEnd = 13 - $startMonth;  As before it wasn't counting the duration of december