# PHP Difference in months between two dates?

Tags: php, datediff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)
>   [Date Difference in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940338/date-difference-in-php)

I have two dates in a variable like

```
$fdate = "2011-09-01"

$ldate = "2012-06-06"
```

Now I need the difference in months between them.
For example, the answer should be 10 if you calculate this from month 09 (September) to 06 (June) of next year -  you'll get 10 as result.
How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: Similar question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681548/find-month-difference-in-php)

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=date+difference+php

Comment: Hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Answer (score 23):

A more elegant solution is to use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).

```
<?php

// @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php
$d1 = new DateTime('2011-09-01');
$d2 = new DateTime('2012-06-06');

// @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php
$interval = $d2->diff($d1);

$interval->format('%m months');
```

Comment: This does not work if the interval is more than 12 months. A difference of 13 months will show up as 1. As a user mentioned in a comment on the other answer, you can use `$interval->m + 12*$interval->y` to fix this.

Comment: Why not post a complete answer, or update this one?

Comment: also, the result of `$interval->m + 12*$interval->y` will always be positive, you have to check `$interval->invert` and multiply by -1 or 1 accordingly : 
`($interval->invert ? -1 : 1) * ($interval->m + (12 * $interval->y))`

Answer (score 16):

Have a look at [`date_diff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php):

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%m months');
?>
```

Comment: i got error while running this...Fatal error: Call to undefined function date_diff() in C:\test\test.php on line 4

Comment: @Jaiff Which PHP version are you running? 5.3 is required for this function.

Comment: This doesn't work, for the example you've provided it will return 0

Comment: @PezCuckow It actually depends on your date settings in PHP, the format is YYYY-DD-MM in this example. Change it accordingly to your own date format.

Comment: My point was, you're not taking into account the year here.

Comment: add in the years with $interval->m + ($interval->y * 12)

Comment: Not a proper solution test for 2009-10-11 and 2009-11-10..

Comment: Calculate no of months between 2 dates:

    $date1 = '2017-01-20';
    $date2 = '2019-01-20';
    
    $ts1 = strtotime($date1);
    $ts2 = strtotime($date2);
    
    $year1 = date('Y', $ts1);
    $year2 = date('Y', $ts2);
    
    $month1 = date('m', $ts1);
    $month2 = date('m', $ts2);
    
    echo $joining_months = (($year2 - $year1) * 12) + ($month2 - $month1);