# How to get the difference in months between two dates in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I wanted to calculate the difference between two dates in month with PHP but it seems like there is a bug somewhere.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$datetime2 = new DateTime(MyObject->getDate());
echo($datetime1->format('d/m/Y'));
echo($datetime2->format('d/m/Y));
```

Result:

```
29/01/2016
27/01/2015

$dateInterval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo($dateInterval->format(%m months);
```

Result:

```
0 months
```

Why is that? What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: In the case you describe, there is no difference in months (they're both January), you'll find that the date interval shows the year property contains 1 as there is one year difference between the dates.

Comment: ok.. I thought it was the difference between 2 dates in months

Comment: `print_r($dateInterval)` can help you understand how the class [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Difference in months between two dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427694/php-difference-in-months-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$currentDateTime = new DateTime;
$dateTimeInTheFuture = new DateTime(MyObject->getDate());

$dateInterval = $dateTimeInTheFuture->diff($currentDateTime);

$totalMonths = 12 * $dateInterval->y + $dateInterval->m;

echo $totalMonths;
```

Answer (score 2):

> Calculate months between two dates:
>
> For **PHP >=5.3** you can use DateTime diff that returns a
>   DateInterval object as below.
>
> ```
> $d1 = new DateTime("2013-12-09");
> $d2 = new DateTime("2014-03-17");
>
> var_dump($d1->diff($d2)->m); 
> var_dump($d1->diff($d2)->m + ($d1->diff($d2)->y*12));
> ```
>
> If you **don’t have PHP 5.3 or higher**, you can use `strtotime()`
>   function to get timestamps, the number of seconds between any date and
>   January 1 1970 00:00:00.
>
> ```
> $d1 = "2013-12-09";
> $d2 = "2014-03-17";
> echo (int)abs((strtotime($d1) - strtotime($d2))/(60*60*24*30));
> ```

http://www.tricksofit.com/2013/12/calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-php

Answer (score 0):

```
// @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php
$d1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$d2 = new DateTime(MyObject->getDate());

// @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php
$interval = $d2->diff($d1);

$interval->format('%m months');
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime::diff` returns relative values, with exception of `days`.
So, to calculate the absolute difference in months, you have to use:

```
$datetime1->diff($datetime2)->format('%y')*12+$datetime1->diff($datetime2)->format('%m');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just missed Single quote termination,

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$datetime2 = new DateTime(MyObject->getDate());
echo($datetime1->format('d/m/Y'));
echo($datetime2->format('d/m/Y'));//You are missing single quote here
```

I am also try with this code,

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-12-13');
echo($datetime1->format('d/m/Y'));
echo "<br/>";
echo($datetime2->format('d/m/Y'));
$dateInterval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
//print_r(arrayColumn($dateInterval,'m'));
echo "<br>Month are :".$dateInterval->format('%m');
exit; 

?>
```