# PHP - Calculate Number of Months between a date and the current date

Tags: php, date

I need to work out the number of months between a date like this:

```
$inputDate = '09/08/2016';
```

that is entered in the MM/DD/YYYY format, and the current date, e.g.:

```
$today = date("m/d/Y");
```

I've been looking at the [date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) but can't seem to get the syntax right here and appreciate any help here.

Comment: @PedroLobito I think they've been here long enough to know what to do, and given their rep score. It's also only been 9 mins. since they posted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Didn't notice the rep! Was on auto mode...

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you please take a look at the comments of my answer? why I'm not able to get the months correctly?

Comment: TBH @PedroLobito I couldn't say. I thought that another of their question http://stackoverflow.com/q/43960129/ might have been relevant in seeing `"date_expires": "2017-05-27",`.

Comment: I've updated my answer, thank you @Fred-ii- !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`diff`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime2 = new DateTime('09/08/2016');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$months = $interval->format('%m months'); # you can also use %a days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds
echo $months;
# 8 months
# optimally you can use:  
# echo $datetime1->diff($datetime2)->y*12;
# or 
# echo $interval->m
```

---

Update based-on comments:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime2 = new DateTime('09/08/2015');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo  (($interval->format('%y') * 12) + $interval->format('%m')) . " full months difference";
```

---

Note:

A `DateInterval Object` looks like:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 3
    [m] => 5
    [d] => 15
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 1264
)
```

That's why we've to multiply the number of `years * 12` and add the `months` in order to get the difference in months. Strange, but this is how it works...

Comment: I just tested this with a date of '05/13/2015' and it's returning 0 months - any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I've no idea why it's returning 0 months, although, you can also get the difference in months using `$datetime1->diff($datetime2)->y*12;`

Comment: I noticed if you change the year on the $datetime2 to 2015 ('$datetime2 = new DateTime('09/08/2015');') it still returns 8 months.

Comment: I'm still looking into this, it's a mystery to me!

Comment: I'm wondering whether this takes into account the years, or only works when the 2 dates are in the same year or less than 12 months?

Comment: I think the most reliable way to get the correct results is using : `echo  (($interval->format('%y') * 12) + $interval->format('%m')) . " full months difference";`, I'll update the answer. Grabbed from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2681841/797495

Comment: This appears to be an issue when the interval is greater than 13 months - see here for a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427694/php-difference-in-months-between-two-dates (use $interval->m + 12*$interval->y to fix this)

Comment: I've updated my answer with an explanation. GL @user982124