# Calculating # of months between 2 timestamps using PHP 5.2

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find Month difference in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681548/find-month-difference-in-php)

My server hosts multiple websites, and with some of the librarys I am using, it will be very difficult upgrading to php 5.3. I plan to do it in the near future, but not at the moment.

I have two timestamps, and I want to calculate how many months are between them. PHP 5.3 has the datetime.diff function, but since I am on 5.2, I currently can not use this.

What alternatives are there for me? I know I can just grab the seconds by subtracting the timestamps and then get the months by assuming every month has 30 days, but I will be needing an accurate result.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I go for this method:

```
$from = explode("-",date("Y-m-d",$fromStamp));
$to = explode("-",date("Y-m-d",$toStamp));
$months = ($to[0]-$from[0])*12+$to[1]-$from[1];
if( $to[1] == $from[1] && $to[2] > $from[2]) $months--; // incomplete month
if( $to[1] == ($from[1]+1)%12 && $to[2] < $from[2]) $months--; // other side
// result in $months
```

Comment: Thank you Kolink, this works great. Very smart approach. One problem though - if today is May 16 and the date I am comparing is June 1, it would count as a full month. I will need to to count as a full month only when it is June 16.

Comment: @MikeGraf That's what the `($to[0]-$from[0])*12` is - years times 12. As for you, steeped, I'll add another line that'll fix that. See edit.