# how to calculate number of months between two datetime in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find Month difference in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681548/find-month-difference-in-php)

say, i have 2012-03-01 and 2013-02-01 saved in database. When calculating number of months in between, i want to get 12 months instead of exact number of days or exact number of months (e.g 11.92 months)
How to do it in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) make this easy (requires PHP 5.3 or greater)

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2012-03-01');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2013-02-01');
$interval = $datetime2->diff($datetime1);
echo (($interval->format('%y') * 12) + $interval->format('%m'));
```

Comment: Looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2681841/679449) answer. Perhaps OP should use a search?

Comment: this is wrong. this ignores years. you have to do `(($interval->format('%y') * 12) + $interval->format('%m'))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$d1 = date_create('2013-01-31');
$d2= date_create('2013-05-12');
$interval= date_diff($d1, $d2);
echo $interval->format('%m months');
?>
```