# PHP Carbon diffInMonths

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

I have a problem with PHP Carbon diffInMonths function.
In some cases I got wrong result. 
For example:

```
$start = \Carbon\Carbon::create(2017, 4, 1);
$end   = \Carbon\Carbon::create(2017, 5, 1);

echo $start->diffInMonths($end);
```

I should get 1 but I got 0.
I use PHP 7.1 and Laravel 5.4.

Does anybody have a same issue? How can I fix it?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

```
$start = \Carbon\Carbon::create(2017, 4, 1);
$end   = \Carbon\Carbon::create(2017, 5, 1);

echo round($start->floatDiffInMonths($end));
```

Comment: Yes, but this method is available since Carbon 2.x.
Carbon 1.x has not this method.

Answer (score 1):

As the Carbon issue on the [github](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/344) says it's a bug.  Here is [more](https://3v4l.org/uH88b).

```
<?php
$d1 = new DateTime("2015-03-01 00:00:00.000000", new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$d2 = new DateTime("2015-05-01 00:00:00.000000", new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));

$diff = $d2->diff($d1);

print_r($diff);
```

output

```
DateInterval Object ( [y] => 0 [m] => 1 [d] => 30 [h] => 0 [i] => 0 [s] => 0 [f] => 0 [weekday] => 0 [weekday_behavior] => 0 [first_last_day_of] => 0 [invert] => 1 [days] => 61 [special_type] => 0 [special_amount] => 0 [have_weekday_relative] => 0 [have_special_relative] => 0 )
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a workaround or how can I solve this problem?

Comment: @MárkPásztor You can use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2681841/6521116